# How to implement Keyed Transient Dependency Injection in C# using IServiceProvider

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-8.0

I have 3 SFTP providers for my application. I am trying to use newly introduced .net 8 Keyed DI feature to register these SFTP providers:

```
var hostname1 = "hostname";
var portNo1 = 22;
var username1 = "username";
var password1 = "password";

services.AddKeyedTransient<SftpClient>("SFTP1", new SftpClient(hostname1, portNo1, username1, password1));
```

Later retreive it like:

```
public IActionResult Get([FromKeyedServices("SFTP1")] SftpClient client)
 {
    do something with the SFTPclient...
 }
```

The issue is that the code is not compiling:

The error is:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1503  Argument 3: cannot convert from 'Renci.SshNet.SftpClient' to 'System.Func<System.IServiceProvider, object?, Renci.SshNet.SftpClient>'   TestSFTP    C:\Users\Windows 10 VM\source\repos\TestSFTP\TestSFTP\Program.cs    18  Active

[image: error screenshot]

I do not know how to use IServiceProvider to register keyed SftpClient.
Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A transient service means "new instance every time it's required".

Therefore, it doesn't make sense to pass an instance to `AddKeyedTransient`, you need to pass a factory method instead:

```
services.AddKeyedTransient<SftpClient>(
    "SFTP1",
    (provider, key) => new SftpClient(hostname1, portNo1, username1, password1));
```

Every time that service is requested from the provider, the factory method is invoked, and you get a new instance.

---

If you do want to register a single instance, then use `AddKeyedSingleton` for that:

```
services.AddKeyedSingleton<SftpClient>(
    "SFTP1",
    new SftpClient(hostname1, portNo1, username1, password1));
```

Comment: Thanks Johnathan, it makes sense why they need a factory for transient and why that is not needed for Singleton.

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide implementation factory in this case:

```
services.AddKeyedTransient<SftpClient>(
    "SFTP1",
    (_, _) => new SftpClient(hostname1, portNo1, username1, password1));
```

`Transient` means that objects are always different so registering a single instance in this case is not expected. From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection#transient):

> ##### Transient
>
> Transient lifetime services are created each time they're requested from the service container. This lifetime works best for lightweight, stateless services. Register transient services with AddTransient.
> In apps that process requests, transient services are disposed at the end of the request.

If you want a single instance then use `AddKeyedSingleton` [(and overload accepting the implementation instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollectionserviceextensions.addkeyedsingleton?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0#microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-servicecollectionserviceextensions-addkeyedsingleton-1(microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-iservicecollection-system-object-0))):

```
services.AddKeyedSingleton<SftpClient>(
    "SFTP1",
    new SftpClient(hostname1, portNo1, username1, password1));
```

Comment: Thanks Guru, can i use discards in lambda or should i use proper or variable names ?

Comment: @perpetual_noob it's up to you. I prefer using discards when lambda parameter is not used.